# Oracle Spatial Objects to Vertex List

Tags: sql, oracle, gis

I am struggling to convert a series of oracle SDOs (polygons specifically) into a more usable format.

I have data that is in this format:

```
PolygonID | Polygon
1         | SDO Geometry
2         | SDO Geometry
3         | SDO Geometry
```

And so on...

What i want to get is the following:

```
PolygonID | Vertex.X | Vertex.Y | Vertex.Order
1         | 1        | 1        | 1
1         | 3        | 5        | 2
1         | 2        | 3        | 3
2         | 1        | 2        | 1
```

And so on. So I just need to polygon converted into a ordered list of vertices. I can successfully convert a single SDO geometry into a ordered list using the below code but cant link it to its polygon ID.

```
select x,y
from table (
  select sdo_util.getvertices( 
               SDO
         )
  from POLYGONS 
  where ID = 1
)
order by id;
```

I am a bit lost on how to link that data back to its original polygon ID. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So I eventually found the solution. See below.

```
SELECT 
     c.POLYGONID, 
     t.X, 
     t.Y, 
     t.ID as ORDER
FROM POLYGONS c,
TABLE(SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES(c.POLYGON)) t
```

The table function creates a sub-query linked to each polygon ID.